# Regular expression for delimiters

Tags: regex, csv, pattern-matching

Need some help with a regular expression

How can I write an expression that filters everything between the delimiters (tab, comma, semicolon)? All the preceeding/trailing spaces must go as well.

Example input

```
Abra Cadabra       ; Harry Potters,Magic Wand[tab]Sucks!
```

Matches

```
[Abra Cadabra]
[Harry Potters]
[Magic Wand]
[Sucks!]
```

Not desired

```
[Abra Cadabra     ]
```

I came up with this to select everything BUT the output wanted

```
\s*[,;\t\n]\s*
```

Is there any way to "reverse" it?

Comment: Just pass your regular expression to a 'split' function.

Comment: Yep, that was actually what I ended up doing, worked like a charm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as simple match/search goes, this one [seems working](http://rubular.com/r/uTpKRTsCit):

```
[^,;\t ]+(?: +[^,;\t ]+)*
```

BTW, I agree with kevin's comment up there, I'd use something like

`string.split(/\s*[,;\t]+\s*/)`

Answer (score 0):

There is such a thing as a [negated character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) (you have to scroll down a bit). Try this:

```
[^,;\t\n]*
```

It works in Expresso, which is .NET-based.

---

Playing with that rubular thing, I think `[^,;\t\n]*\b` may give you what you want...

Comment: If you are returning matched strings, would it be acceptable to just `trim` the leading/trailing whitespace? If the regular space character is not a delimiter but should not be in a match, it makes this a bit trickier.

Comment: Sure... I just wanted to see if it was possible, since it would be more efficient and less code :)

Comment: Just add `\b` in front and we have the solution! `\b[^,;\t\n]*\b`

Comment: @hakanito, that only picks up Sucks but not Sucks!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use this.

```
\s[^,;\t\n]*\s*
```